# using relationship with Core Data On iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 entries
1. category (main one)
2. info

the relationship is 1 to many , for every category there is several info's

after i added the several info classes to each categoty
i want to get each category relationship list in the `detailsviewcontroller`

I created a temp class in the details view the contain the selected category
how do i get access to the list of INFO'S ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code or model classes, I can't give you the exact answer.  But when you made your model, you probably named your relationship something like "infosForCategory".  When you generated the model it made a NSMutableSet for that 1-to-many relationship.  In that case, you can access the list of infos with:

```
NSMutableSet *myInfos = myCategory.infosForCategory;
```

Comment: I've tried that and when i'm checking the size of the nsset I get 0. maybe i'm not adding the info object correctly. this is my code for adding the info object: [currentCategory addProvideInfoToCategotyObject:currentInfo]; //i'm using the function and not the asset, maybe this is the issue.

Comment: That should work.  Put a breakpoint at that line and verify that neither currentCategory nor currentInfo are nil.  You can also go directly into the DB on your simulator and query it to see what's actually in it. Find DB here: /Users/<you>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/<long string of letters & nums>/Documents and use terminal to "sqlite3 MyDatabase.sqlite".  Then use SQL queries to see what (if anything) is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but it sounds like you already have an instance of `Category` and you want to retrieve all the related instances of `Info`. In that case, `Category` should have an automatically generated `info` property that is of the `NSSet` type. That set will contain all of the related `Info` objects.

Comment: this the function 

- (void)addProvideInfoToCategotyObject:(Info *)value;
- (void)removeProvideInfoToCategotyObject:(Info *)value;
- (void)addProvideInfoToCategoty:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeProvideInfoToCategoty:(NSSet *)values;

Comment: i'm using the first one. i also has a nsset, but because i'm parsing and xml file i can add one info object at each time when i get to the tag